# below 23 android xiaomi devices permission

Tags: android

So I have camera permission in manifest , Still when app goes to start camera  it crashes .this happens beacuse user had denied the permission in permission manager for camera that comes with xiaomi devices

So the app Crashes , can someone help about how to handle this.

with the normal way of getting permisions , it does not give correct result

`String permission = "android.permission.CAMERA";
 int res = getContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);`

res is always 0(has Permission) for below 23  devices , if user has manually denied permission by going to permission manager then also

Comment: I recommed just go through this once https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: @PreetikaKaur  ya i know android dynamic runtime permissions for device>=23 for below i check if they have permisison through above code , but for xiaomi device below 23 ,from permission manager u can deny the permission but the normal way of picking permission returns true because that permission is still there in manifest. but app crashes because xiaomi hase denied it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revoking permissions on android devices below 23 is non-standard behavior and is afaik only possible through customized OS versions (like Cyanogen mod or in your case, the Xiaomi modified version). Users should be aware, that revoking permissions that way may cause error ins apps.

> Prior to Android 6.0, you could reasonably assume that if your app is running at all, it has all the permissions it declares in the app manifest.
>   https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/best-practices.html#testing

Therefore I suggest you run your methods that require a certain permission with a try/catch. If the api lvl is below 23 and your method call fails, you know for sure if you have the permission or not.